# Meteor app deployed to Heroku fails with CloudFlare Flexible SSL

Tags: heroku, meteor

Just deployed my meteor app to heroku using heroku-18 and meteor-buildpack-horse. This is deploy v116. On previous deployments I was able to use Cloudflare flexible SSL configuration on my app, but after deployment v116 the page keeps redirecting to the login route. As I can see from logs, I think it may be related to log entries with status 101 (Switching Protocols).

If I access my app through http://app.domain.com it works, but accessing with https://app.domain.com it doesn't.

**Heroku app logs**

```
2018-10-17T23:52:16.299384+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/048/yk_lctvs/websocket" host=app.domain.com request_id=8d322763-1141-4217-94e1-5b390e1e9739 fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.96" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=765ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:16.336802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=app.domain.com request_id=9d1fe273-3abb-4ecf-996f-ced82b07117e fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=4442 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:16.512511+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=5g7x6pmg9k" host=app.domain.com request_id=dfd71b44-5b95-42b3-b02f-bd118e91804a fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=200 bytes=363 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:17.119755+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=jadymh88hj" host=app.domain.com request_id=0febb4b3-107a-41ad-b427-6f187a32c3b2 fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=363 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:18.401775+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/559/3by4bm5x/websocket" host=app.domain.com request_id=85b5cf5b-7c75-4472-9a0e-46c76c8cd534 fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.95" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=664ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:18.410152+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=app.domain.com request_id=ebd62bbc-a041-40aa-9c21-e15414655a59 fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=4442 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:18.616711+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=7k081p4ay5" host=app.domain.com request_id=a780d8d5-a149-4a55-a43d-b9be9dbfd1bc fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=363 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:19.144127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/info?cb=3zq5040dzp" host=app.domain.com request_id=a86deb0d-8ee1-4ed6-9c60-88ea639afb7e fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=363 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:20.417289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=app.domain.com request_id=1f7bf690-22a2-44c6-bfc2-76de3bef3558 fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.114" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=4442 protocol=http

2018-10-17T23:52:20.405086+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/sockjs/802/r48516e0/websocket" host=app.domain.com request_id=2f733dc7-2d60-4770-b83d-52f53b5bc58a fwd="181.95.179.168,162.158.123.96" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=662ms status=101 bytes=175 protocol=http
```

**UPDATE**

This issue seems to be related to meteor package [browser-policy](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/browser-policy). After disabling it in meteor packages file and removing the startup code the site stopped redirecting.

The startup code for browser-policy is as follows:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { BrowserPolicy } from 'meteor/browser-policy-common';

BrowserPolicy.framing.disallow();
BrowserPolicy.content.disallowInlineScripts();
BrowserPolicy.content.allowInlineStyles();
BrowserPolicy.content.disallowEval();

const trusted = [
  'maps.googleapis.com',
  'maps.gstatic.com',
  'csi.gstatic.com',
  'dinamo-server-meteor.herokuapp.com',
  'dinamoapp.playtime.com.ar',
  'fonts.googleapis.com',
  'fonts.gstatic.com',
  'cdnjs.cloudflare.com',
  'unpkg.com',
  'a.tile.openstreetmap.org',
  'b.tile.openstreetmap.org',
  'c.tile.openstreetmap.org',
  'blob:',
];

_.map(trusted, origin => BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll(origin));
```